# I want to frequently check the server for new data.Using C# TImers

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to frequently check the server for new data. means i want to fire the select command for every 20 minutes to check database table. i am using windows form application 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You could [use a Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer). And the [corresponding documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

```
var timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).TotalMilliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    // TODO: send a query to the database
};
timer.Start();
```

In Windows Forms you could also use the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

If the app does nothing else I recommend [scheduling it](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Working-Windows-Server-2008-Task-Scheduler-Part1.html). Scheduling the app frees you from a whole set of problems ranging from not having to implement Service-behaviour to avoiding instability due to not freeing unmanaged resources over time. Apps running for a long time can encounter problems, crash, freeze, etc. The task scheduler has options to kill  long running apps and similar, so it is a good friend for such tasks.

If the app modifies its GUI use [System.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) (drag out a timer GUI control to the form).

If the app runs in the background use either [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) or a dedicated [System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) with a wait loop containing [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx).

If your app runs from ASP.Net then rumor has it [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is the way to go. Personally I'd recommend you don't run schedules from ASP.Net and instead take a good look at your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz.NET is a very good library. I'm using it in my windows services. I suggest you should use [cron trigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html).

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/